# WPF Binding is delayed somehow (Error)

Tags: wpf, binding, delay

I have a problem with a WPF application. Somehow it seems that two (out of several) bindings in my WPF control are not immediately applied. When I look into the visual tree with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), the binding is suddenly applied and everything works fine.

What can be the reason for that?

The XAML code is here:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
    <m:Map ZoomLevel="12" Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <m:Map.CredentialsProvider>
            <m:ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider ApplicationId="???"/>
        </m:Map.CredentialsProvider>

        <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding Station.Location, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" />
    </m:Map>
    <Button Command="{Binding CenterOnAddressCommand, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"
        Content="Adresse zentrieren" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
</Grid>
```

The binding of the `Map.Center` property works and the other two bindings (on Pushpin and Button) don't. The Map control is from the Bing Maps WPF Control.

**EDIT:** 
After some further investigation I tried removing the binding to the Map.Center property and then everything works (well except centering the map on a certain position). How can this be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The converters don't even get called?

Comment: Exactly, they get called when I look at the binding in Snoop but not before that :(.

Comment: Not that I know what to do with this information but if you give it a bad binding name does PresentationTraceSources give you an error?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything if I bind to some non-existing property :(.

Comment: Could it happen that the map control is invisible when you open the window? If so, it might not get templated before made visible, while touching it with Snoop might trigger initialization.

Comment: No unfortunately it is visible from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Two tips:

1. Try upping the verbosity of the WPF messages displayed in the Output window. You can do this by going to `Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > WPF Trace Settings` and changing `Data Binding` to something like `All`.
2. Add an `UpdateSourceTrigger` attribute to the bindings that are failing - it may be that the bindings aren't being told to update. Maybe Snoop triggers application-wide binding updates.

I hope that helps you find the cause of your problem.

Comment: 1. There are no binding errors (since the binding isn't even "applied" till I select the element in snoop (at least that's what I think happens).

2. Adding an UpdatSourceTrigger didn't help :(.

I tried removing the binding to the Map.Center property and then everything works (well except centering the map on a position). How can this be?

Comment: Does the verbose binding output give you any information (not necessarily errors) that indicates something is working with the bindings you're having issues with? Try comparing the outputs when you have the `Map.Center` property binding, and when you don't. You may see some useful difference.

Answer (score 0):

What about the m:Map control? Is that honoring the values when it is being initialized? ie if you give a fixed value for property is that working.

Try [Reflector](http://.NET%20Reflector%3a%20Decompiler%20and%20Assembly%20Browser%20%7C%20.NET%20Reflector%20www.reflector.net/) to verify the code of the Map control.

Comment: Yes it does honor fixed values.